# How to execute a Query/access sharepoint list in MS Project?

Tags: vba, soap, sharepoint, powerquery, ms-project

I need to populate my resource list in MS Project from a Sharepoint list. The authentication method for sharepoint is the windows credential/company credentials.
I was thinking by SOAP or a query already saved (this will be better since I have the processing Power query). What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

This can actually be pretty interesting depending on how much access your SharePoint farm admin folks allow you to have.

SOAP is fine probably. But I've always used REST to access a SP List through SP's API. I've used this site: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/complete-basic-operations-using-sharepoint-rest-endpoints to great effect when creating and accessing lists from remote applications. Anything that can send an authenticated rest / generate a token with credentials should be able to get the LIST and even edit it.

One thing to remember among the many nuances of SP development is that list names are often different when accessing through SOAP or REST API points. You may need to figure out your own List naming conventions and any special character codes like underscore or spaces and their corresponding SP codes ((http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/787/finding-the-internal-name-and-display-name-for-a-list-column))

*EDIT* if you have power query, you can use the built in connect to sharepoint template in most Office Apps that feature PQ. That might be good, since it should allow you to save the credentials you have to get the SP without having to generate a token through SOAP or REST. But REST is my main experience here. I've used PQ in Excel to access SP list.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I think I would like to use the SharePoint template , since my credentials are company based. Any info on that specifcally?